# Form a sequence of integers at specified interval in bash

Tags: bash, sequence

I create a sequence with interval `1` using `{0..4}` syntax alright:

```
$ for i in {0..4}; do echo  $i; done
0
1
2
3
4
```

However, when I set interval explicitly at `2` using conventional syntax `{0..4..2}`, it doesn't work:

```
$ for i in {0..4..2}; do echo  $i; done
{0..4..2}
```

And the expected output should be:

```
0
2
4
```

My bash version:

```
$ echo ${BASH_VERSION}
3.2.25(1)-release
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ for i in `seq 0 2 4`; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thank you! ...Still wondering why `{0..4..2}` is not working.

Comment: @koch No problem! From what I know, that curly brace step syntax only works in zsh, ksh93, and I believe bash 4+.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the syntax:

```
$ for ((i=0; i<=4; i+=2)); do echo $i; done
```